# Pass a parameter to a function in php from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a function in php that receives an address from an s3 bucket and returns a signed url. Like this:

```
 public function getUrlSigned (){
   $url = parse_url(urldecode($_GET['path']);
   //CODE FOR GET URL SIGNED
   //  
   return urlSigned;
 }
```

How could I pass $s3Url from the client side that I have saved in the database ??

the objective is to be able to view your image in your private profile

I have tried with this:

```
<img id="imageDNIback" th:src="'https://SERVERSIDE/getUrlSigned/?path=' + ${urlS3}" alt="noIMG"/>
```

But it does not work

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do. If you're trying to pass the URL from the server to the client (as seems most likely), just `echo` it from whichever PHP script produces this page. (Or maybe you're using a templating system, but that will provide a way to call this function and output the result in the HTML, surely.) Or if you're trying to pass something from the client to the server for processing, you'll have to make an Ajax request.

Comment: (I'm not that familiar with S3, but it occurs to me there might perhaps be security issues with passing something like this to client-side code. You'll know better than me if that URL is supposed to be secret or not.)

Comment: AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. In a nutshell, it is the use of the XMLHttpRequest object to communicate with servers. It can send and receive information in various formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and text files.

Comment: @RobinZigmond The url that is in the database cannot be shown because it is in a private bucket, so I have to get a signed URL.  I'm not familiar with request ajax, but I'm going to try this. Thank you